# Hashimoto thyroiditis leading to severe psychological problems and behavior changes?

Tags: mental-health, endocrinology, autoimmune-disease, hypothyroid, hashimoto-thyroiditis

Can Hashimoto thyroiditis lead to psychological problems and severe behavioral changes?

Do existing psychological problems (anxiety, depression, etc.) 'compound' when layered with Hashimoto thyroiditis?

Comment: Unfortunately, my answer was deleted. I am sure that the moderator wouldn't have done so if he or she had read the referenced paper. I will not repeat my explanations even in modified form. Instead, you might want to read the papers at http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24419358 and at http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26635726 .

Answer (score 5):

A literature search (as well as my education) reveal the following:

[Hashimoto thyroiditis](http://europepmc.org/abstract/med/16444160) causes inflammation of the thyroid hormone producing cells in the thyroid gland.  This can lead to hypothyroidism as the [associated symptoms](http://jama.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=375004).  In the initial phase though, the inflammation may cause a sudden "leaching" out or release of the already formed thyroid hormone causing a hyperthyroid state known as Hashimoto thyroxicosis which can produce hyperthyroidism [related symptoms](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1532-5415.1996.tb05637.x/abstract;jsessionid=891E49A6D55B583194EDA6E17543D4B0.f02t04?systemMessage=Wiley%20Online%20Library%20will%20be%20unavailable%20for%20up%20to%203%20hours%20on%20Saturday%2019th%20March%202016%20from%20%2011%3A00-14%3A00%20GMT%20%2F%2007%3A00-10%3A00%20EDT%20%2F%2019%3A00-22%3A00%20SGT%20for%20essential%20maintenance.%20%20Apologies%20for%20the%20inconvenience.&userIsAuthenticated=false&deniedAccessCustomisedMessage=).

Please see sources above but speaking from my knowledge in addition to the above:  Essentially Hashimoto thyroiditis can cause an initial hyperthyroid state.  Hyperthyroidism can cause nervousness, tremor, and other neuropsychiatric symptoms.  If a patient then later develops clinical hypothyroidism, they can also suffer the neuropsychiatric consequences of hypothroidism which include depression, though can be very severe including coma.

Thyroid hormone acts on many tissues and can essentially affect any organ system.  The symptoms therefore can be very broad and nonspecific.  The symptoms may also be severe.  The psychiatric symptoms are well known.  **Therefore, the answer to your question is, yes.**